# How do I retrieve firebase child data without also retrieving the key?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm currently trying to get the child data without the key in an array so I can add that to my redux state.

```
ref.orderByChild(`userId`).equalTo(googleUserInfo[0].userId).once('value', streamSnapshot => {
        if (streamSnapshot.exists()) {
          googleUserInfo[0] = (streamSnapshot.val())
        }
```

Currently this returns

```
[{…}]0: {-LbJneodI2SaUglB6fwx: {…}}length: 1__proto__: Array(0)
```

But I would like this

```
[{…}]
0:
{
displayName: "Seth Jones"
userAvi: "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-RABcz3kK1ew/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/ACHi3rfzHCLV9A7LfiGWKtTOuq5rJmtQpg/s96-c/photo.jpg"
userEmail: "xxxx@gmail.com"
userFirstName: "Seth"
userId: "103977654052015523435"
userLastName: "Jones"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

You need to loop over the results, to get to the individual values:

```
ref.orderByChild('userId').equalTo(googleUserInfo[0].userId).once('value', streamSnapshot => {
    streamSnapshot.forEach((child) => {
      googleUserInfo[0] = (child.val())
    });
```

Comment: Thanks bud! Short and sweet, exactly what I needed.